# "Абсолютно на все" — как лучше сказать?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Снижать цены абсолютно на все" или "на все абсолютно"? Равноценны ли оба варианты и как сказать правильнее?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В принципе, возможны оба варианта. Но смысл у фраз разный.

*Снижаем цены абсолютно на всё.* - снижаем цены на все товары без исключения.

*Снижаем цены на всё абсолютно.* - снижаем цены на все товары до минимально возможных.

Answer (score 0):

> Снижаем цены на всё абсолютно. - снижаем цены на все товары до минимально возможных

Мне кажется, в этом  случае от перестановки слов смысл не меняется: уж больно далеко друг  от друга  находятся слова "снижаем" и "абсолютно". Тогда уж "Абсолютно снижаем цены на всё"

Comment: Смотря как знаки препинания расставить. *Снижаем цены - на всё абсолютно*, действительно отнести "абсолютно" к снижению цен невозможно . Но без тире, хочется отнести определение ко всему предложению целиком, а главные члены предложения - "цены снижены". Для рекламного слогана изменение смысла от пунктуации - крайне нежелательно.